# Fetching Object value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript development.I have been working on objects with javascript.When i reffered and tried a code with javascript object i found an error with it ..The code is

```
var and = { models:"AN",

 collection:{},

 name: function() { var babe = 5; return babe; } 

}
```

When i called the code with `and.name( { name:"george",age:20} );` it gives me output as `5`.

But when i called like `and.name.age` it shows me undefined instead of `20`.

Since am new to javasscript i didnt get what am doing wrong ..Hope you guys can help me out ..Thanks in advance

Comment: what actually you want to do ?

Comment: The `name` is not a object. You have not defined a `age` property  on the `name` and thats is why you get `undefined`

Comment: You are getting that undefined because your `name` field is a function so it can't have a age field there.

Comment: @Mritunjay i want to call like and( { name:"george",age:20 }) and display age 20 as 20 when we call and.name.age

Comment: @Mritunjay can you post an answer in which situation we want to use like and.name( { name:"george",age:20 }) and how can we retreive value from it ??

Comment: I think you should not do that because then you will overwrite your name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this might be helpful for you.

```
var obj = { models:"AN",
 collection:{},
 person:{},
 changeDetails: function(values) {
    obj.person.name = values.name;
    obj.person.age = values.age;
  } 
};

obj.changeDetails({name:"George",age:20});
console.log(obj.person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `name` attribute is a function, not an object that contains a "`age`" attribute...

Calling a function will return you the value setted in the return statement.

Calling an attribute by its name will give you its value.

I would advise you to try a tutorial about the basics of javascript to understand the differences...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the mix between a function and an object:

```
var and = { models:"AN",

 collection:{},

 name: function() { var babe = 5; return babe; } 

}

and.name = { name:"george",age:20}

alert(and.name.age)
```

Try this in jsfiddle.

Here I change the function name with an object. Then I get the value you want.

Hope it helps.